# Is a Azure Stream Analytics job with sparse/ none output possible?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Not the best question, I'm aware but I couldn't find much information on this and currently lack the time to test it.

Is it in principle possible with Azure Stream Analytics to only forward an output if some condition is met? In the docs it states: "You can use a single output per job, or multiple outputs per streaming job (if you need them) by adding multiple INTO clauses to the query."

So for example would it possible to do something like insert `INTO destination` only if some condition is met and not do produce an output otherwise (or would this raise an error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, whenever some input event does not match the WHERE condition that you specify in your query, the event will just be discarded.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/where-azure-stream-analytics